# Creating Contact returns ResourceNotFound error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an error of `ResourceNotFound` while integrating and calling `POST v1.0/me/contacts`:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-01T15:45:47",
            "request-id": "76062d8a-e541-4a52-ae08-9b196dd8e07d",
            "client-request-id": "dd8b8c41-22bb-2b78-c926-3063ef313ba0"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same from Graph Explorer:

[image: Error Image]

**Note:** token is used, API permissions given.

Can anyone please guide/help on this issue?

Comment: Please check if you have the proper exchange license.

Comment: This is typically due to the user not having a mailbox provisioned (which is where Contacts are stored). The quickest way to confirm this is to try logging into the [Outlook](https://outlook.office.com/owa/) web client.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I have created a different new account and using the outlook domain, and assign the required permission finally it works for me. @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :)